# Excel Pivot Table VBA: How to put Sums in Row Labels

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have am trying to create a Pivot Chart from a set of test data. It is almost working, but to show the chart the sum of data has to be in the Row Label Box.

I can do it easily by hand, but this is supposed to work using VBA. The rest of the table and chart is being generated using VBA and it works well, but I don't know how to move the SUM field into the Row Labels

Move Sum of Data from Column Label to Row Label:
[image: Move Sum of Data from Column Label to Row Label]

```
sourceSheet.Select
Set dataRange = sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(currentRow - 1, startColumnVals + columnArraySize - 1))
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, dataRange)
Set pTable = pCache.createPivotTable(pivotSheet.Range("A42"))

' Page fields are the filters
Set pField = pTable.PivotFields("Result")
pField.Orientation = xlPageField

' Column fields will apprear in the Legend
Set pField = pTable.PivotFields("TestName")
pField.Orientation = xlColumnField


' Row Fields - don't know what to do here !

' Data field
For i = 0 To (columnArraySize - 1)
    cellText = sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumnVals + i).Text
    Set pField = pTable.PivotFields(cellText)
    pField.Orientation = xlDataField
    pField.Name = "S" & cellText & "-" & i
    pField.Function = xlSum
Next

Set dataRange = pTable.TableRange1

Set pChaObj = pivotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=1000, Top:=15, Height:=500)
Set pChart = pChaObj.Chart

pChart.SetSourceData dataRange
pChart.ChartType = xlLine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Set pField = pTable.PivotFields("value")
pField.Orientation = xlRowField
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need the "(Sigma)-Value" Entry in the Row field. Please click on Link to Image (just above the code). I don't have enough reputation to embed images :-(

Comment: Sorry, you were right after all. Only my installation is German, so I had to use "werte" instead of "value". Also the entry has to be made after the data-Fields have been defined (else Orientation will refuse to work).